# Bad Image Format Exception when creating record in database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework(model first) in my C# project ,and i am using SQL Server as database.When i'm trying to add a record in a table i encounter this exception.
What's the problem?[image]

Comment: the BadImage Exception happens when you mix the architecture of DLLs (x86, x64). Which CPU architecture have you selected for your project?

Comment: @magicandre1981: I don't think you'd get "Bad IL range" with architecture mismatch issues though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is unrelated to that line. If you view the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) for that exception, it says:

> The exception that is thrown when the file image of a dynamic link library (DLL) or an executable program is invalid.

Together with the message, "Bad IL range," I would think you have a corrupted assembly somewhere.

**Possible solutions**

- Look at the exception details to determine which file for which the exception was thrown

  - If it's a file built by your project, try to clean solution and rebuild
  - If it's a library, reinstall it
- Check if you have anything processing your assemblies, like an obfuscator -- see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carmelop/archive/2013/06/13/system-badimageformatexception-bad-il-range-what-it-is-going-on.aspx)
- *Last resort*: check for viruses, hardware issues, and reinstall .NET

Comment: The error was solved after reinstalling Entity Framework, thanks.